# Markdown Preview Rendering Bug on Large Posts

Tags: support, bug, edits, markdown, markdown-rendering

> Answer have since been modified to workaround this bug but the behaviour can still be seen by looking at this specific revision edit.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35985827/edit/02e154d6-eee2-4a94-b233-aa2e78f156c0
>
> *Please don't press `Save Edits` though or it will replace the current content.*

Decided that a common question needed a definitive answer for once, but after beginning to structure the answer realised it's going to take a lot of explanation. This was fine until the Markdown Preview in Edit Mode began to screw up after entering a certain amount of characters (approx. 4000 or so).

<strike>Is it possible I'm hitting a hard limit of what markdown can format?</strike>

Has anyone else come across this?

---

**Update:**

I've just noticed that adding the extra text causes the markdown preview to go *[skew-whiff](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:skew-whiff)* but when I submit the changes the formatted answer is correct, possibly just an issue with the preview?

> Not embedding the images as it becomes confusing distinguishing between the images and the question.

[Screenshot of Markdown Formatting issue *(highlighted problem formatting)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85prm.png)

Above is a screenshot of the preview in Edit mode you can see in the highlighted area how the markdown is failing to format correctly.

[Screenshot of Formatted Answer After Save Edits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIkHu.png)

When submitted with `Save Edits` though it formats correctly

---

**Update:**

Tried [@cody-gray's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318943/mark-preview-in-edit-mode-stops-rendering-correctly#comment321819_318943) of removing the `<pre>` HTML tags and the preview formats correctly.

I was using `<pre>` as a quick way to build none syntax code blocks for command line and references in registry etc, until now I've not had a problem using them. Instead I used the

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

approach and the preview works fine.

---

#### HTML Rendering Bug?

Does this mean there is a bug in the `<pre>` HTML rendering when previewing markdown in Edit Mode?

> <sup>[Comment excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318943/in-large-posts-the-markdown-preview-on-edit-mode-doesnt-render-after-certain-nu#comment321819_318943) from [@code-gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)</sup>
>   *"This may still be a bug though, if HTML tags are supposed to be supported as first-class citizens."*

Comment: Yes, the limit is 30,000 characters, which should be more than enough for an answer. This includes any markdown and links.

Comment: If editing the question don't do what I did and click the `Save Edits` link in [the picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/85prm.png) instead of the actual `Save Edits` button.

Comment: My guess would be that you're formatting the markdown incorrectly. I can't say for sure, since you don't show us the actual markdown syntax that you're using there. Lots of people have trouble making things work the way they want when putting text inside of a list.

Comment: @CodyGray My first thought as well but when I submit the changes the formatting is correct in the answer. I didn't want to post the whole markdown it's over 4000 characters which is why I posted an image of the preview showing the markdown formatting bug.

Comment: Well if you successfully posted it, you could always link to the answer. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray http://stackoverflow.com/a/35985827/692942

Comment: Yeah, I found it in your profile. I'm not sure why you are using `<pre>` tags. That appears to be causing the problem. When I [reformat](http://pastebin.com/psnKXJUf) using only Markdown, the preview renders correctly. (The key is indenting *8* spaces to get code formatting inside of a bulleted list, rather than the normal 4.) This may still be a bug though, if HTML tags are supposed to be supported as first-class citizens.

Comment: @CodyGray I use `<pre>` to avoid issues with syntax highlighting, I could just use `<!-- language: lang-none -->` though, just being lazy. Didn't realise `<pre>` tags would cause a problem, good catch!

Comment: @CodeGray Switching all the `<pre>` tags to `<!-- language: lang-none -->` fixes the preview issue, thank you. But isn't there still a bug with the `<pre>` tags?

Comment: @Lankymart `<pre>` tags also have HTML inside them striped, and something like `<pre>hello <a test></pre>` will have the `<a test>` part striped. Even worse, `<pre>hello <a test</pre>` will break the `<pre>` tag. Just don't use 'em, if you want a code block, indent by four spaces. The button or CTRL+k shortcut should make that just as easy, if not easier, than adding `<pre>` tags and doesn't have these (and perhaps other?) problems.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker You know you can do `<pre>hello &lt;a test&gt;</pre>` right and it will format it as `<pre>hello <a test></pre>`? But agree `<pre>` seems buggy just not had any issues with it before but then I don't usually write answers this long.

Comment: @Lankymart I don't know about you, but I don't particularly enjoy going through all my code examples/errors/program outputs/log files to make sure that there are no characters in there that need to be represented as a HTML entity. It's especially dangerous since the errors are "silent" (i.e. you don't actually get an error, but wrong output).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I wouldn't use `<pre>` for "code blocks" for that very reason, but if I'm showing a command line output, a registry key path etc., then usually I would to avoid the syntax highlighting that occurs without `<!-- language: lang-none -->` defined before the code block *(as I mention in the 2nd update on the question)* by using a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Also, if I remove *only* the last `<pre>` it works. If I add back and empty `<pre>\n</pre>` (`\n` for newline) it seems to break again, but not with `<pre></pre>` ... :-/ Adding `<pre>\n</pre>` elsewhere does seem to work :-/

Comment: For anyone curious (like me) what "screw whiff" is, [here's an article](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6227) about where it comes from... :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That is actually a typo it should be *["skew whiff"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=skew%20whiff)* but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Raw HTML Blocks nested inside list items, which is not permitted according to the original [rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements — e.g. `<div>`, `<table>`, `<pre>`, `<p>`, etc. — must be separated from surrounding content by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the block should not be indented with tabs or spaces.

I realize that not all Markdown implementations follow this rule and some do support nested raw HTML, but I find it is not always fully tested and unreliable. The best approach it to simply avoid doing it.

Comment: Are you saying you shouldn't even use code blocks inside list items or just the raw HTML versions?

Comment: I'm saying Raw HTML should be avoided inside list items. Markdown code blocks are fine.

Comment: It does appear as though that is the best option.